# Today Extension Breakpoints not triggered in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, lldb, xcode8

I try to debug my Today Extension. When I run the scheme for the Today Extension on my Device I can see all NSLogs. But all Breakpoints get ignored so far. The host app can be debugged normally.

That means I already attached my Today Extension target to the debugger.

I already tried to delete the DerivedData folder.
I already tried to reset my Xcode Defaults.

`break list` returns all breakpoints which are set.

Any ideas?

Comment: only select the Today extension schema and put the break points and run the application then it will catch the debuger

Comment: No, that does not work. Just the logs are showing up.

Comment: Try Like that step by step First run the application with host app after once run the app complete then stop them and again select Today extension schema and set the break point in view did load or view will appear and run the application it will open the app with today extension and catch the debuger

Comment: Does not work. It just prints my logs... when there is an NSException it is the only breakpoint which gets triggered.

Answer (score 3):

when I was developing today extension, I was debugging it like this:

1) I ran my app on device

2) Debug > Attach to process by PID or Name > type my_process_name ( see screenshot )

3) Click attach, then it worked

[image]

Comment: Nope, does not work. I tried it with Xcode 8.3.2 and Xcode 8.2.1.

Comment: Find the process name of the pid does not seem to work.. What I did
was to used the "Target Name" of the Today Extension. I also noticed that I needed to touch the Today Extension before the debugger would find and attach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the problem:

It is necessary to add each source file to the Today Extension Target. Otherwise it is not possible for the Debugger to find the breakpoint in my case.
But this is more complicated to change. Because of our current architecture. But now I do know that Xcode works as appropriate.

Comment: If your extension was missing files it needed, you probably couldn't compile it, or if you did, it would crash. You would never get far enough for the debugger to be a problem. If you're talking about files that the extension doesn't need, then there's never any reason to include them in the extension target.

Comment: I did not write the code for this extension. The architecture is just whole different than I expected it to be. There were no missing files. They were wrapped and therefor it is not possible to debug the today extension as usually. The host app is also not containing the files. So I need a new approach for debugging. But this is not relevant for this question.